# JacksonJaxbJsonProvider ignoring @JsonFormat in my entity

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson, cxf

I'm creating a cxf client and adding JacksonJaxbJsonProvider in my client.
I'm posting an object which has a date field annotated by @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd").

The issue is that my json provider is not taking consideration the @JsonFormat and serializing my date field in another format.
Can anyone please help on fixing this?

Comment: And all your other Jackson annotations are working as expected?

Comment: Some code/configuration here might help